# Java pattern regex with escape characters

Tags: java

I want to replace `";"` with `"\n"` except when it's escaped with a leading '\'. I haven't figured out the correct regex.

Here is what I have:

```
String s = "abc;efg\\;hij;pqr;xyz\\;123"
s.replaceAll("\\[^\\\\];", "\\\\n");
```

I'd expect the above string to be replaced with `"abc\nefg\;hij;pqr;xyz\;123"`

Comment: just `s.replace("\\;", "\n");`

Comment: I don't want to replace \; with \n. Only the semicolons with new line. I fixed the regex above.

Comment: So, @DarthNinja, when you said "I want to replace '\;' with '\n'" -- you didn't mean that...is that right? Ask the question you mean, please.

Comment: @Darth what about the other semicolons - after `"hij"` and `"pqr"`? Or do you only want the *first* semicolon to be replaced?

Comment: All unescaped semicolons to be replaced with new line. Any \; should be excluded.

Comment: Instead of generalizing incorrectly, @DarthNinja, just give a few examples of what you want to change and what it should be changed to. It's much simpler for us to help you when you're clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look behind:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\);", "\n");
```

The expression `(?<!\\)` (coded as a java string literal `"(?<!\\\\)"`) means "the previous character should not be a backslash"

---

Test code:

```
String s = "abc;efg\\;hij;pqr;xyz\\;123";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\);", "\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
abc
efg\;hij
pqr
xyz\;123
```